# Word Counter from Text - counting 'a' in 'absolute'

Tags: python, count, set

Trying to create a program that reads from a text file and prints the word and its respective count on a new line.

e.g.
been: 3
having: 1
those: 1

Problem I am getting is that it will count the word a for every instance the letter a appears within a word. e.g. a cat fell off the mat - returns a count of 'a' 3 times, instead of 1.

Below is my code.

```
# Save the results
with open('my_text.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(text)
    file.close()

# Read sanitised text
with open('my_text.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_text = file.read()
    collection = my_text.split()
    print(f'Total Count: {len(collection)}')
    collection = set(my_text.split())
    print(f'Unique Count: {len(collection)}')

# Extract count per word and print
for word in collection:
    instances = (f'{word}: {my_text.count(word)}')
    print(instances)
```

Above the code i have some functions to remove punctuations, lower case, etc.

Approach:

1. Create list
2. Create set
3. Check each word in set back to original list, and count.

Apologies - only a couple weeks into Python, so i appreciate my code may not be very good.